# How to change time tracking unit from hours 'h' to days 'd' in sprint taskboard?

Tags: azure-devops

Is there any way or workaround to change time tracking unit from hours 'h' to days 'd' in sprint taskboard in Azure Devops (ADO)? We've searched on Google and came across few articles. So sharing them here.

- https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/1095445/user-story-card-erroneously-displays-hours-when-ti.html
- https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/960792/capacity-planning-using-story-points.html

[image: ado]

We want to change the highlighted unit 'h' to either 'd' or show nothing at all. Any extension or plugin for Azure Devops which can solve this problem would be really helpful. Or if there is any settings option (either Project settings or Organization settings) from where we can alter the taskboard's view would be helpful.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not get your response for several days, would you please share your latest information about this issue? If you have any concern, feel free to share it here.

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid that currently only "hour" is supported in azure devops service to show the sprint capacity in taskboard.

As stated in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/queries/query-numeric?view=azure-devops#fields-used-to-estimate-and-track-work):

> **Note**: For **Azure Boards**, the taskboard **always shows** "h" for hours in
> relationship to Remaining Work. For **TFS**, you can modify the
> ProcessConfiguration file for the Remaining Work type field to specify
> "d" for days, or other preferred label.

Until now, in our official feature suggestion for Azure Devops forum, there has been a such [suggestion](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/849967/need-a-way-in-the-work-details-pane-to-change-h-to.html) exist in it. You can comment and vote it there. So product team would provide the updates if they view it. Thank you for helping us build a better Azure DevOps.

Comment: Apologies @HughLin-MSFT. But the answer doesn't provide what I was looking for.

Comment: Until now, in our official feature suggestion for Azure Devops forum, there has been a such [suggestion](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/849967/need-a-way-in-the-work-details-pane-to-change-h-to.html) exist in it. You can comment and vote it there. So product team would provide the updates if they view it. I will also help you vote it.